# Facebook Api: Some of my target information is not showing up, even though friends facebook pages have it

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to use the fb graph api to gather some information about facebook friends, and the scope of the project kind of depended on all of the fields here (to create a sorting algorithm based on the data).

Unfortunately when I gather all of the data (which takes forever) several of the fields for the friends data are missing. I expected some to be missing, but over half doesn't give me location information, and the all of the religion information is not showing up. I checked some of the friends individual facebook pages to which the data is there and revealed to me as a friend of theirs (they have a current location for instance). Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it just something I can't do. If there another way to gather this, I am open to suggestions. Any thoughts at all would be great!

```
  $config = array(
    'appId' => '###############',
    'secret' => '########################',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      try {

        //User Data
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $locationId = $user_profile['location']['id']; 
        $location = $user_profile['location']['name'];
        $platform = $facebook->api('/'.$locationId,'GET');
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'] . "<br />";
        echo "Gender: "  . $user_profile['gender'] . "<br />";
        echo "Birthday: " . $user_profile['birthday']. "<br />";
        $date = explode("/", $user_profile['birthday']);
        $age = date("Y") - $date[2];
        echo "Age: " . $age . "<br />";
        echo "Religion: " . $user_profile['religion']. "<br />";
        echo "Hometown: " . $user_profile['hometown']['name']. "<br />";
        echo "Location: " . $location . "<br />";
        echo "Longitude: " . $platform['location']['longitude']. "<br />";
        echo "Latitude: " . $platform['location']['latitude']. "<br />";

        //Friend Data
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends', 'GET');
        echo "<br />";
        echo "Friend Test <br />";
        foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
            $c_id = $value['id'];
            echo $c_id. "<br />";
            $c_friend = $facebook->api('/'.$c_id);
            echo "Name: ". $c_friend['name'] . "<br />";
            echo "Gender: ". $c_friend['gender']. "<br />";
            echo "Birthday: ". $c_friend['birthday']. "<br />";
            echo "Religion: ". $c_friend['religion']."<br />";
            echo "Hometown: ". $c_friend['hometown']['name']. "<br />";
            echo "Location: ". $c_friend['location']['name']. "<br />";
            $c_locationId = $c_friend['location']['id'];
            if($c_locationId)
            {
                $c_platform = $facebook->api('/'.$c_locationId,'GET');
                echo "Longitude: ". $c_platform['location']['longitude']. "<br />";
                echo "Latitude: ". $c_platform['location']['latitude']. "<br />";
            }

            echo "<br />";

        } 



      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "user_religion_politics,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,friends_religion_politics,friends_birthday,friends_hometown,friends_location"));
        echo "Place 1 <br />";
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "user_religion_politics,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,friends_religion_politics,friends_birthday,friends_hometown,friends_location"));
      echo "Place 2<br />";
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One word, **privacy**, using Facebook Graph API to gather information doesn't mean you can bypass the user privacy and leak all their data

Comment: Even if the information is not hidden? I suppose I don't understand why I can access the information manually, but not through the app.